# how we can access child window from parent window?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

can we get property of an element of child window from parent window.
I want to get a url inside child window using JavaScript. is it possible?

for Example:

```
let newwin = window.open('https://anyweb.ext/anypage');
let URL = newwin.document.getelementbyid('knownIDinChildWindow').href;
```

I just know id of a  element in child window.

Comment: You can only access other windows if they're in the same domain as your document.

Comment: So unless your page is also in `anyweb.ext`, you can't do this.